# Как сделать, чтобы при клике выпадало окошко на javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, php, css

Вопрос не точный - извиняюсь.

Надо, чтобы при клике на ссылке в меню в том же окне выпадала, к примеру, информация о сайте.

Подсказали использовать якорь( # ).
Меню строится на php и добавляется в html страницу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если совсем грубо, то:

```
<script>
function showTab(n)
{
    var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for(var i = 0, pl = p.length; i < pl; ++i)
    {
        if(i == n)
            p[i].style.display = 'block';
        else if(/(\b|\s)?tab(\b|\s)?/.test(p[i].className))
            p[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
<a href="#" onClick="return showTab(0);">Ссылка 1</a>
<a href="#" onClick="return showTab(1);">Ссылка 2</a>
<p class="tab" style="display:none">Таб1</p>
<p class="tab" style="display:none">Таб2</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо сделал сам не пригодилось)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону [jQuery](http://jquery.com/): на главной страницы есть пример того, что вам нужно.

Comment: Сделал именно на jQuery задача была из разряда "Колбасу резать сложнее"